# Is there a way to import later in golang?

Tags: import, go, exec

I'm writing a small go program. I expect it to be run on different OSes, so I was hoping to use go run rather than including the compiled file. The problem is it uses a package from outside the standard library. I don't want to rely on people having the package. I can get the package using

```
package main

import "os/exec"

func main() {
    _ := exec.Command("go", "get","github.com/user/library").Run()
}
```

But by then it's too late to import it. I can see three solutions.

1. Make a wrapper script.
2. Cross-compile
3. Get the user to do it

But I'd really like to install it and then import, is there any way to do so?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. a) You really shouldn't be using `go run` like that b) if you expect it to run with `go run` that means `go` is installed so they can just `go get` your program and it'll get and install whatever is needed.

Comment: Cross-compile. `GOOS=linux ./make.bash` at the root of your Go installation, then `GOOS=linux go build github.com/me/foo`. The cross-compilation support is pretty good for pure-Go programs, and you can't load packages at runtime like that.

Comment: LOL, that is a very creative use of the exec command. Self compiling go bins. It might be possible, but you would need two executables: one that sets up the $GOPATH with the dependencies and one actual program. Oh and users will need a working go toolchain. You might be better off with distributing [cross compiled](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/08/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go) binaries

Comment: plus1 for creativity

Answer (score -1):

Just host your code on github or somewhere else. Then the people who want to run the program can use `go install "example.com"` to get a binary.

If you dont want to host your code, you can instruct them to put it in their `GOPATH/src/` and use `go install yourprojectsname`.

Comment: No, `go run` does not (at least on my Go1.4.2 system); only `go get` fetches dependant packages. A `go get .` (?) or `go get <go-gettable_URL_for_OPs_program/package>` will get and build everything required.

Comment: @DaveC: Fixed my mistake.